# Missing migration files

Tags: django, database-migration, rollback

I am stuck at this error for missing migration files.. Do I need to drop the whole database to reset the migrations or is it possible to do some type of migrate rollback for that app gigs?  Does anyone know how to solve it? Would highly appreciate the help!

[image: Terminal error for migration]

Comment: What happened to gigs 003?

Comment: 002 and 003...gone -.-

Comment: And are they in your `django_migrations` database table? There's a command something like `python manage.py showmigrations` which can list everything in the terminal and show if it's been applied yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can go back to one migrations before 0003 with `python manage.py migrate gigs 0001`

Comment: it says "Unknown command: 'gigs'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage." and that last part gives "bash: manage.py: command not found"...I have not change the name of the app!

Comment: throws the same error..I dont understand..'python manage.py migrate gigs 0001' makes sense..why error

Comment: Are you in correct directory? Your env is activated?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

1)

I manually had to delete all the migration files accept **init**.py, and made migrations again.Used senario 3 from this link:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html

2)

- python3 manage.py showmigrations
- python3 manage.py makemigrations
- python3 manage.py migrate

3. 

Reset the postgres in Heroku Config Vars and in gitpod variables.

4)

Run 'git push origin HEAD:master' to connect master branch again.